# how can i forbid the copy/paste option of a textbox in vb.Net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a textbox that is managed by the keyDown event which limits insertion 4 characters but when the user makes a copy / paste it DePace 4 character! So is that it is possible to prohibit this option.

thank you in advance

Comment: Why not use the [MaxLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextBox CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="textBox_PreviewExecuted"/>
```

**C#**

```
private void textBox_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy ||
        e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut  ||
        e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub textBox_PreviewExecuted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    If e.Command Is ApplicationCommands.Copy 
         OrElse e.Command Is ApplicationCommands.Cut 
         OrElse e.Command Is ApplicationCommands.Paste Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

To Disable using Keys as(Ctrl+C,Ctrl+V) use following code:

**C#**

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(control, this.OnCancelCommand);
DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(control, this.OnCancelCommand);

private void OnCancelCommand(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
{
    e.CancelCommand();
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(control, AddressOf Me.OnCancelCommand)
DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(control, AddressOf Me.OnCancelCommand)

private void OnCancelCommand(Object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
    e.CancelCommand()
```

Comment: @shinekings I managed to do this for the first code, but to ctrl + C / Ctrl + V I dont know what I should do in vb.net